# С++ списки добавление

Tags: c++, visual-c++

У меня есть программа, она работает, но сказали, что нужно разделить списки, а как это сделать я ума не приложу. Я так понимаю, у меня двунаправленность добавление списков, а мне нужно однонаправленные списки. Кто-то сможет мне показать, как это сделать у меня в программе:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h> 
 
using namespace std;
 
struct node 
{
    double inf;
    node* next, * prev;
};
 
struct list 
{
    node* head = nullptr, * tail = nullptr;
    int kol_n = 0;
    list() {}
 
    void clear() // очистка
    {
        node* ptr1 = head, * ptr2 = head->next;
        while (ptr2)
        {
            ptr1 = ptr2;
            ptr2 = ptr2->next;
            delete ptr1;
        }
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        kol_n = 0;
     }
 
    ~list()
    {
        (*this).clear();
    }
 
    void add(double n) // добавление
    {
        kol_n++;
        if (tail) {
            tail->next = new node;
            tail->next->prev = tail;
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        else {
            head = tail = new node;
            tail->prev = nullptr;
        }
        tail->next = nullptr;
        tail->inf = n;
    }
 
    void print() // печать
    {
        node* ptr = head;
        if (ptr)
        {
            while (ptr)
            {
                cout << ptr->inf << ' ';
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
        else cout << "Нет элементов\n";
    }
 
    void summ_proizv() 
    {
        if (kol_n >= 2)
        {
            double S = 1;
            node* x1 = head;
            node* x2 = head->next;
            node* xn = tail;
            while (x2)
            {
                S *= (x1->inf + x2->inf + 2 * xn->inf);
                x1 = x1->next;
                x2 = x2->next;
                xn = xn->prev;
            }
            cout << "S = " << S << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Мало элементов в списке" << endl;
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    list lst;
    double n;
    char ogranichitel = ' ';
    cout << "Введите элементы пробел, заканчивая ввод Enter: ";
     while (ogranichitel != '\n')
    {
        cin >> n;
        lst.add(n);
        while (true)
        {
            ogranichitel = cin.peek();
            if (ogranichitel != ' ') 
                break;
            cin.get();
        }
    } 
    printf("\nСозданая последовательность: ");
    lst.print();
    lst.summ_proizv();
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да в общем-то тут всё просто - вы в структуре узла создали указатель на следующий и предыдущий элемент. Просто уберите указатель на предыдущий элемент из структуры и код с ним связанный. Только тогда вы не сможете двигаться по списку в обратном направлении (с конца в начало) в функции `summ_proizv()`

```
struct node 
{
    double inf;
    node *next;
};

void summ_proizv() 
{
        if (kol_n >= 2)
        {
            while (x2)
            {
                xn = xn->prev; // не получится!!!
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Ну и в случае вызова `clear()` у пустого списка у вас будет UB.

```
void clear() // очистка
{
    node *ptr1 = head, 
         *ptr2 = head->next; // UB если список пустой head == nullptr
```